# Посоветуйте сервисы для баг репортов андроид

Tags: android

Нужен внедряемый сервис для андроид приложения, который позволял бы пользователям оставлять сообщение разработчику об ошибках или доработках.

Comment: play.google.com?

Comment: Там пользователь должен оставлять оценку и логично, что если присутствует ошибка, то оценка может быть не высокой, а если был бы внутренний сервис, то пользователь в дальнейшем не оставлял бы плохой отзыв

Comment: firebase я использовал для этого

Comment: @Cypher у меня как раз интегрирован, что за сервис в нем?

Comment: @Cypher можно конечно и на коленке сделать с добавлением введённого пользователем в бд, но слишком костыльно

Comment: просто записываете оценку в бд firebase и какие нибудь данные о юзере(модель самртфона и тд)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 3):

Самый внедряемый сервис для контакта юзеров с разработчиками это как мне кажется электронная почта :) Для этого нужно добавить в любой используемый вами обработчик событий вызов приложения отправки почты:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

отправку можно осуществлять не только на один но и на несколько адресов:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses); // String[] addresses
```

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email). Так же можно использовать [ACRA](https://www.toptal.com/android/automated-android-crash-reports-with-acra-and-cloudant) но он больше используется как репортер при крашах.

Comment: Электронная почта - с моей точки зрения самый плохой способ. Я не хочу отправилять имейл, я хочу ввести в форму текст и отправить. Особенно бесит, когда в приложении есть форма для ввода баг-репорта, вводишь текст, а после нажатия на "отправить" открывается имейл для отправки.

Comment: Не плохой вариант, но немного другое хотелось бы, так как даже условно регистрации в моем варианте может не быть. Просто поле и кнопка отправить, возможно заголовок еще